# Help understanding LINQ expression

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, join

Hi i'm try to debug some code but can't work out what it's doing.

```
// For reference, the following is roughly equivalent to:
// select   p.* 
// from     CTBEquitiesFiles as o inner join CTBEquitiesDetailStaging as p 
// on       o.ID = p.CTBEquitiesFiles.ID
// where    o.SEFileDate = fileDate and o.SEFileType = 'W'

mdovar depositRows = fileRepo.Query(o => o.SEFileDate == fileDate && o.SEFileType.Equals("D"))
    .Join<SE.TradeDetailFile, SE.TradeDetailStaging, int, SE.TradeDetailStaging>(
        detailRepo.Get(),
        o => o.ID,
        p => p.CTBEquitiesFiles.ID,
        (o, p) => p);
```

I'm fairly sure it's not doing what I want. I want to get all the rows from CTBEquitiesFilesDetailsStaging where the SEFileID column is the same as the ID column in CTBEquitiesFiles.

Thank you

Comment: If it's not doing what you expect, you have to tell us what it *is* doing. We can't run your code to see what's happening. Also, `o.SEFileType = 'W'` should have "D" instead of "W".

Comment: @Gabe: I think the OP is wondering about debugging the code within the query.

Comment: @Gabe: I disagree with your suggestion I think `o.SEFileType.Equals("D"))` show have a "W" instread of "D" :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what queries are being issued to the database, you can [use the sql profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx), or [set the DataContext.Log property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log.aspx).